# ViewController loads but does not show

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, spotify

I'm using the Spotify iOS SDK. When a user logs into Spotify using the app, on call back `loginVC` transitions to `musicPlayerVC`. But, when a user logs into the app using a web view, once the web view dismisses and the `loginVC` is shown, the `musicPlayerVC` is loaded (print statements from `viewDidLoad` occur), but `loginVC` does not dismiss and `musicPlayerVC` does not show.

`loginVC`:

```
class loginVC: UIViewController, SPTStoreControllerDelegate, WebViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    var authViewController: UIViewController?
    var firstLoad: Bool!
    var Information: [String:String]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.sessionUpdatedNotification), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "sessionUpdated"), object: nil)
        self.statusLabel.text = ""
        self.firstLoad = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.sessionUpdatedNotification), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "sessionUpdated"), object: nil)

        let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()
        // Uncomment to turn off native/SSO/flip-flop login flow
        //auth.allowNativeLogin = NO;
        // Check if we have a token at all
        if auth!.session == nil {
            self.statusLabel.text = ""
            return
        }
        // Check if it's still valid
        if auth!.session.isValid() && self.firstLoad {
            // It's still valid, show the player.
            print("View did load, still valid, showing player")
            self.showPlayer()
            return
        }
        // Oh noes, the token has expired, if we have a token refresh service set up, we'll call tat one.
        self.statusLabel.text = "Token expired."
        if auth!.hasTokenRefreshService {
            self.renewTokenAndShowPlayer()
            return
        }
        // Else, just show login dialog                                
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func getAuthViewController(withURL url: URL) -> UIViewController {
        let webView = WebViewController(url: url)
        webView.delegate = self

        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: webView)
    }

    func sessionUpdatedNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.statusLabel.text = ""
        let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()
        self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
        if auth!.session != nil && auth!.session.isValid() {
            self.statusLabel.text = ""
            print("Session updated, showing player")
            self.showPlayer()
        }
        else {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Login failed."
            print("*** Failed to log in")
        }
    }

    func showPlayer() {
        self.firstLoad = false
        self.statusLabel.text = "Logged in."
        self.Information?["SpotifyUsername"] = SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.canonicalUsername

        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            [weak self] in
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowPlayer", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowPlayer" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? PlayController {
                destination.Information = self.Information
            }
        }
    }

    internal func productViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: SPTStoreViewController) {
        self.statusLabel.text = "App Store Dismissed."
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
    }

    func openLoginPage() {
        self.statusLabel.text = "Logging in..."
        let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()
        if SPTAuth.supportsApplicationAuthentication() {
            self.open(url: auth!.spotifyAppAuthenticationURL())
        } else {
            self.authViewController = self.getAuthViewController(withURL: SPTAuth.defaultInstance().spotifyWebAuthenticationURL())
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            self.present(self.authViewController!, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
        }
    }

    func open(url: URL) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                      completionHandler: {
                                        (success) in
                                        print("Open \(url): \(success)")
            })
        } else {
            let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            print("Open \(url): \(success)")
        }
    }

    func renewTokenAndShowPlayer() {
        self.statusLabel.text = "Refreshing token..."
        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession(SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session) { error, session in
            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session = session
            if error != nil {
                self.statusLabel.text = "Refreshing token failed."
                print("*** Error renewing session: \(error)")
                return
            }
            self.showPlayer()
        }
    }

    func webViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: WebViewController) {
        // User tapped the close button. Treat as auth error        
    }
}
```

`webController` :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

@objc protocol WebViewControllerDelegate {
    func webViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: WebViewController)
    /*! @abstract Invoked when the initial URL load is complete.
     @param success YES if loading completed successfully, NO if loading failed.
     @discussion This method is invoked when SFSafariViewController completes the loading of the URL that you pass
     to its initializer. It is not invoked for any subsequent page loads in the same SFSafariViewController instance.
     */
    @objc optional func webViewController(_ controller: WebViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool)
}

class WebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    var loadComplete: Bool = false
    var initialURL: URL!
    var webView: UIWebView!
    var delegate: WebViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(initialURL)
        let initialRequest = URLRequest(url: self.initialURL)
        self.webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.webView.delegate = self
        self.webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.done))
        self.webView.loadRequest(initialRequest)
    }

    func done() {

        self.delegate?.webViewControllerDidFinish(self)
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        if !self.loadComplete {
            delegate?.webViewController?(self, didCompleteInitialLoad: true)
            self.loadComplete = true
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
        if !self.loadComplete {

            delegate?.webViewController?(self, didCompleteInitialLoad: true)
            self.loadComplete = true
        }
    }

    init(url URL: URL) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.initialURL = URL as URL!

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Comment: Your method `open(url: URL)` will not open `URL` in your `WebViewController`.

Comment: @NiravD Yes, that only calls when the user owns the Spotify app

Comment: Don't you using storyboard?

Comment: @NiravD Yes I'm using storyboard

Comment: Then why are you not initiating the `WebViewController` using `storyboard. instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`?

Comment: @NiravD Oh im sorry I misunderstood, the WebViewController is not a separate ViewController inside my storyboard file. Refer to the `getAuthViewController` function.

Comment: That was i'm asking, you are currently initializing `WebViewController(url: url)` why you not initializing `WebViewController` using `storyboard. instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` ?

Comment: @NiravD Because doesn't require a ViewController in storyboard with an identifier? I don't have that.